# Logging in Spark

Tags: logging, apache-spark, slf4j

I downloaded pre-built `spark 1.4.1`, set the java home to `openjdk-1.7.0-jdk` and added it to the `PATH` variable. When starting the master I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
```

I added all possible `slf4j 1.7.12` jars to the `CLASSPATH`, one at a time, but the problem persists. Help please !

Comment: What command are you trying to run?

Comment: ./sbin/start-master.sh

Comment: Can you paste the entire output then?

Comment: failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Log file content : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger

Comment: I mean the output from the start of ./sbin/start-master

Comment: Just 2 lines which are : 
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/...
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
   ... 6 more
full log in /home/...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a slf4j-simple file to your dependency is going to fix the issue. Try this for gradle build
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.21'